# Could I use this Speaker Wire for my thermostat?

Tags: thermostat-c-wire, wire, speakers, gauge

I had this wire left over and thought I might as well use it if I can. I think it will work but I just wanted to make sure! So can I use this speaker wire for the Rc and C terminals on my thermostat? The other end will be going to a 24volt AC transformer...more specifically: [https://www.amazon.com/Elk-TRG2440-24VAC-Transformer-Fuse/dp/B0007N5LJK/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_product_top?ie=UTF8](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0007N5LJK)

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Typical "thermostat wire" is a NEC/UL type CL2 cable, just like your speaker wire says it is, so as a replacement for an 18/2 thermostat cable, this will work just fine.